# Laravel React with react router on other route causes 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

Im having issues with laravel route,
Im making a multiple react projects which uses `react-router-dom` and I want them to be separate instead on one project build

Below is the webpack setup to generate 2 separate folder of react project:

```js
mix.webpackConfig({
   resolve: {
      alias: {
         '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'js'),
         '@admin': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'js', 'Application', 'Admin'),
         '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'sass'),
         // '@components': '/resources/assets/js/components'
      }
   }
})
.react('resources/js/Application/Admin/app.js', 'public/js/Admin')
.react('resources/js/Application/LandingPage/app.js', 'public/js/LandingPage').sourceMaps()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

On the laravel route, this is my configuration:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('lading-page');
});
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
});
```

Root.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Signin from './Pages/Signin'
import Auth from './Pages/Auth/App'
import Dashboard from './Pages/Auth/Dashboard'
import Users from './Pages/Auth/Users'
import PageNotFound from './Pages/PageNotFound'

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Auth />}>
          <Route path="" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

The landing page is working fine,
But when I use the `admin` route it says `404 not found` which is the `react-router-dom` 404 handler *not Laravel route handler*

My question is, to solve this issue?
Is there a way or does Laravel React support's Laravel routing to render specific view ?

Answer (score 0):

Just got solve the issue:
So in my case I was using `BrowserRouter` on react route, this method will definitely edit the URL when routing and this method is the same as laravel route, thats the conflict happen.
To fix this have to use `HashRouter` which will add `#/` to the routes and not causing conflicts to Laravel route

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter